# How to disable clicking on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a memory game using JavaScript and jQuery and now I want to disable clicking the image (card) that is opened on click. I have tried `img.onclick=false`, `img.onclick=null`, but it does not work. Below is a part of my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    checkIfMatch(this);
  });
});

function checkIfMatch(img) {
  arrayIMG.push(img);
  img.onclick = false; //here I want to disable the clicking
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting to have more than one element in the `arrayIMG` eventually? If you want to match just 2 images to each other, having just a single possible element there would make more sense

Comment: Yes, in arrayIMG I collect all the images (cards) that are clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest tweak would be to only push the image to the array if it's not already in it:

```
function checkIfMatch(img) {
  if (!arrayIMG.includes(img)) {
    arrayIMG.push(img);
    // do other stuff when an image is clicked, if any
  }
}
```

If you don't need to do other stuff when a new image is clicked, you could make things even easier by using a Set instead (which will automatically condense duplicates):

```
const arrayIMG = new Set();
function checkIfMatch(img) {
  arrayIMG.add(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To turn off a jquery click handler, you use:

```
$(..).off("click");
```

this is the opposite of `$("..").on("click", function...` which is can be written short-hand as `$(..).click(function...`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    checkIfMatch(this);
  });
});

var arrayIMG = [];
function checkIfMatch(img) {
  arrayIMG.push(img);
  //img.onclick = false; //here I want to disable the clicking
  $(img).off("click");
  
  // toggle to show that it only gets called once
  $(img).toggleClass("active");
  console.log("click")
}
```

```css
.active { border: 5px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width=320/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" width=320/>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a singe-click mechanism:

```
$(..).one("click", function
```

which will automatically turn off the click event once clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").one("click", function() {
    checkIfMatch(this);
  });
});

var arrayIMG = [];
function checkIfMatch(img) {
  arrayIMG.push(img);

  // no need to "turn off" click as only run once
  
  // toggle to show that it only gets called once
  $(img).toggleClass("active");
  console.log("click")
}
```

```css
.active { border: 5px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width=320/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" width=320/>
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `.off("click")` will remove *all* click handlers, not just the one added here.